# lessc command cannot find import inside another import

Tags: less, lessc

I have an issue with running `lessc` command when there is hierarchical imports. My folder structure is like this:

```
(root)/
|--- website
     |--- styles
          |--- master.less
|--- library
          |--- testDir
               |--- child.less
          |--- test.less
```

The short version of **`master.less`**:

```
@import url('../../library/test.less');
```

The short version of **`test.less`**:

```
@import url('/testDir/child.less');
```

When I run `lessc website/styles/master.less website/styles/master.css`, I am given `FileError: '/testDir/child.less' wasn't found. Tried - /testDir/child.less, etc`.

**Note**: It is not viable for me to use `--include-path=./library/testDir` option, because I have many instances of these hierarchical imports in my less files.

Any other option that I am missing, or a workaround?